# Error: Unexpected eof while parsing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im writing my first code and can't figure out what this error means and what i should fix, Please help. Error: Unexpected eof while parsing

```
import math

def circumference(r):
return 2 * math.pi * r

def area(r) :
return math.pi * radius**2 * r

fName = input("Please enter your first name: ")
lName = input("Please enter your last name: ")
radius = float(input( fName + " " + lName + " , please enter your radius: "))


print("Hello %s %s Your circumference is %s and your area is %s " % (fName, lName, circumference(radius), area(radius))
```

Comment: how do your run your script?

Comment: you forget a closing parenthesis at the end

Comment: and if you using python3, you can use `str.format()`, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) some examples

Comment: Put a `,` at the end of the last element of the tuple, this way -  `print("Hello %s %s Your circumference is %s and your area is %s " % (fName, lName, circumference(radius), area(radius), )`

Answer (score 0):

You need to close every parenthesis you open. The line of code that is probably causing the error is this:

```
print("Hello %s %s Your circumference is %s and your area is %s " % (fName, lName, circumference(radius), area(radius))
```

You're missing a ")" at the end.